# Is it possible to extends a class but not its superclass

Tags: javascript, class, oop, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I have a class Foo that extends Clickable.

Is it possible to create a class Bar to inherits all the properties of Foo but not Clickable?

If not, is there a workaround?

```
class Clickable{
    click(){
        console.log('clicked')
    }
}
class Foo extends Clickable{
    fooTitle:string;
    fooDuration:string;
}
class Baz extends Clickable{
    bazColor:string;    
}
class BarExtendsFooButIsNotClickable extends Foo{
    barAge:number;
}
```

Comment: Could you specify what exactly you want to avoid from Clickable class in class Bar

Comment: All of its propreties (clickable in this example)